# Google Analytics 4 API Error with R - Request failed 500 - with a specific query, other queries work as intended

Tags: r, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to query the product sold the last week froma GA4 property with googleAnalyticsR package.

I can run multiple queries for other metrics and dimensions but I keep getting an error for this specific query:

```
top_products_sold_last_week <- googleAnalyticsR::ga_data(property_id,
                                                   date_range = c(last_monday, last_sunday),
                                                   metrics = c("itemPurchaseQuantity", "itemRevenue", "averagePurchaseRevenue"), 
                                                   dimensions = c("nthWeek", "itemId"),limit = -1)

Request failed [500]. Retrying in 1.8 seconds...
Request failed [500]. Retrying in 2.4 seconds...
i 2022-08-08 10:43:33 > Request Status Code:  500
i 2022-08-08 10:43:33 > Trying again:  1  of  1
i 2022-08-08 10:43:36 > All attempts failed.
Error in `abort_http()`:
! http_500 Internal error encountered.
```

`last_monday` and last sunday are dynamically generated and are both correct since in the other queries I get a correct response from the api.

I tried to manually query with the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/query-explorer/) and I get a correct response, what am I missing?

This is the JSON request from the Query Explorer

```
{"dimensions":[{"name":"itemId"},{"name":"nthWeek"}],"metrics":[{"name":"averagePurchaseRevenue"},{"name":"itemPurchaseQuantity"},{"name":"itemRevenue"}],"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2022-08-01","endDate":"2022-08-07"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

It does seem like a bug as I can replicate it, could you raise an issue on the project GitHub page? https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/googleAnalyticsR/issues

You can still progress if you have valid JSON by using the `raw_json` parameter with your request e.g.

```r
raw <- '{"dimensions":[{"name":"itemId"},{"name":"nthWeek"}],"metrics":[{"name":"averagePurchaseRevenue"},{"name":"itemPurchaseQuantity"},{"name":"itemRevenue"}],"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2022-08-01","endDate":"2022-08-07"}]}
'

ga_data(propertyId = propety_id, raw_json = raw)
# Making API request with raw JSON:  {"dimensions":[{"name":"itemId"},{"name":"nthWeek"}],"metric ...

# # A tibble: 10,000 × 5
   itemId  nthWeek averagePurchaseRevenue itemPurchaseQuantity itemRevenue
   <chr>   <chr>                    <dbl>                <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 5016395 0000                    15177.                    2      3390. 
 2 5048751 0000                     9378.                   44      8798.
```

Comment: thank you @MarkeD, I'm going to open an issue right now, I wasn't sure if it was a problem of my code